# SIP demo - Error code -10, no data connection

Tags: android, networking, sip, voip

I want to create an application in which user can share their phone camera with each other. I started with the sip demo but could not find a way to register myself on the server. I have created an account on **sip.linphone.org** and entered it as my domain and account's username and password as my username and password in sipdemo. As a result I got error "no data connect, error code -10" and after some time "connect timeout, error code -5" on my phone but my wifi is working fine. I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SIP is ban in Pakistan. So, no data connection for port 5060 either using UDP or TCP. By using proxy on mobile its only possible.